# Pry: "next" command don't work as I expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I'm trying to debug with Pry. Most of the times, whenever I use `next` command to jump over the next line, pry goes to what it seems another frame. For example, watch my code:

```
Item.where(dst: "book").each do |book|
    ott = book.ott
    est = extract_es_title(ott) if ott != nil
    web_item = Item.find_by(su: GR_BASE_URL+book.id)
    binding.pry
end

class Item
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :su, as: :source_url
    field :ott, as: :other_titles
    field :dst, as: :details_structure
end
```

If I run the code, it stops at the correct breakpoint. However, if I run `next` once in Pry console, it goes what it seems deeper in the stack instead of jumping to the next line. Here is the code that Pry shows mw once I run `next`:

```
    645: def yield_document(document, &block)
    646:   doc = document.respond_to?(:_id) ?
    647:     document : Factory.from_db(klass, document, criteria.options[:fields])
    648:   yield(doc)
 => 649:   documents.push(doc) if cacheable?
    650: end
```

Why is this behavior? How can I just jump to the next method line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use breakpoints:

`break 4` then hit `CTRL-D` or type `continue` and it should take you to line 4. Generally "next line" is considered the next line of execution, not the next line of your current file.

From docs: https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to the next iteration of the `each` block. You can just move the binding.pry to the beginning of the loop, and run `continue` each time.

```
Item.where(dst: "book").each do |book|
    binding.pry
    ott = book.ott
    est = extract_es_title(ott) if ott != nil
    web_item = Item.find_by(su: GR_BASE_URL+book.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not the loop, but Pry going deeper in the stack instead of going to the next line.